# C crashes after reading last line of a file

Tags: c, crash

Ive been working on writing a C program that will open a file, scan and store its contents into an array and then do a comparison between designated pairs. The reference is finding mutations within a string of dna.

My problem exists when attempting to read the last line of the file. if i comment out that line everything runs fine but when i try to incorporate the function that reads the line, the program crashes.

here is what i have so far, i know its not very efficient as of yet but I'm still learning

(the line with the stars indicates the one commented out to get the program to run)

```
infile = fopen ("sequences.txt", "r");
outfile = fopen ("mutations.txt", "w");

read_top_pair(infile ,top_pairs, 15);
read_top_pair(infile, bottom_pairs, 15);

read_top_pair(infile, top_pairs2, 6);
read_top_pair(infile, bottom_pairs2, 6);

print_dna_sequence (top_pairs, 15, bottom_pairs, 15);
print_dna_sequence(top_pairs2, 6, bottom_pairs2, 6);

read_top_pair(infile, sick_top_pairs, 15);
read_top_pair(infile, sick_bottom_pairs, 15);

read_top_pair(infile, sick_top_pairs2, 6);
//read_top_pair(infile, sick_bottom_pairs2, 6); ***********************

print_dna_sequence (sick_top_pairs, 15, sick_bottom_pairs, 15);
print_dna_sequence (sick_top_pairs2, 6, sick_bottom_pairs2, 6);

check_mutation(top_pairs, bottom_pairs, sick_top_pairs, sick_bottom_pairs, outfile);

return 0;
```

Here is the function I am calling:

```
int read_top_pair (FILE *infile, char top_pairs[], int size_top_pairs)
{
    int index = 0, base = 0;
    do
    {
        fscanf (infile, "%c", &base);
        if (base != '\n')
        {
            top_pairs[index++] = base;
        }
    } while (base != '\n');
    size_top_pairs = index;

    return top_pairs[15];
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why is wont run with that line included. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: What is the size of the `sick_bottom_pairs2` array?

Comment: What sort of error is the program crashing with?

Comment: Where abouts in read_top_pair does it crash. If you don't know try attaching a debugger and stepping thought one line at a time.

Comment: Each array has a max size of 15. when i run it with that last line

Comment: window immediately tries to debug the file without turning anything up, ill try the step by step debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing values to top_pairs without checking if you're exceeding it's size given by size_top_pairs. As pointed out before if the size of sick_bottom_pairs2 is small you're having a classic buffer overflow.

If this does not help you might try using fgetc(..) instead of fscanf(..) since I'm not completely sure if it handles the end-of-file correctly.

```
int read_top_pair (FILE *infile, char top_pairs[], int size_top_pairs)
{
    int index = 0, base = 0;

    do
    {
        //fscanf (infile, "%c", &base);
        base = fgetc(infile);
        if (base == EOF)
        {
            /* you've reached the end of infile */
            break;
        }

        if (base != '\n')
        {
            /* do this only if (index + 1) is less than size_top_pairs */
            top_pairs[index++] = base;
        }
    } while (base != '\n');
    size_top_pairs = index;

    return top_pairs[15];
}
```